# チャットに紐づけられたアカウントがじぶんのものではない

Tags: サポート

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40568) のコメントのやりとりがモデレータによってチャットに移動されています。

このチャットのアカウント（[137662](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/137662)）に紐づけられたスタック・オーバーフローのアカウント（[5443](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/5443)）は、現在のじぶんのものではありません。じぶんはチャットを利用したことがなく、モデレータが移動させただけなのでどうしてこのチャットアカウントが使用されたのか不明です。

スタック・オーバーフローとチャットのアカウントが整合性のとれた状態になってほしいのですが、どうしたらよいですか？

スタック・オーバーフローの問い合わせに二度送信しましたが返信が全くありませんでした。自己解決するにも情報収集がしたいです。前述のコメントをチャットに移動したモデレータさんはどのように作業しましたか。

---

発生の経緯:

1. スタック・オーバーフローに登録（同時に Stack Exchange ユーザとなる？）
2. 何らかの理由で `chat.stackexchange.com` のアカウントが作成される

   - `parent user` はスタック・オーバーフローのアカウント
   - チャットを利用した覚えがないので、連動して自動的に作成？
3. スタック・オーバーフローを退会する

   - チャットのアカウントは削除されていない（と思われる。他のサービスとも連携があるので）
   - チャットの `parent user` は削除されたスタック・オーバーフローのアカウントのまま
4. 同じメールアドレスで新しいユーザとしてスタック・オーバーフローに登録

一般ユーザが得られる利用状況からの推測しかできませんが、退会した際、チャットの `parent user` が削除されたスタック・オーバーフローのアカウントのまま放置され、その後変更できないのが問題だと考えています。

Comment: 現在 Stack Exchange に三回目の問い合わせを送り、チャットのほうのユーザプロフィールの削除を求めています。チャットのほうのアカウントが一度削除され正しいアカウントでチャットの利用を始めれば解決するかもしれない、という仮定によります

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*自己回答*

チャットのユーザープロフィールの `parent user` を変更するには `[change]` をクリックします。このとき、空白のテキストフィールドが出現します。**選択肢がないようにみえますが、テキストフィールドをダブルクリックするか何らかの入力をし、再度空白に戻すなどするとプルダウンメニューが現れる** ので、任意のサイトを選択してください。

じぶんが当初同じような操作をした際はプルダウンメニューは出現しなかったように記憶しています。新しいサイトに登録すればそれが選択肢に現れるのではないかと仮定し、新しく Ask Ubuntu に参加し `[change]` を試みた結果、プルダウンメニューが表示されました。もしかしたら、新しい登録なしでもメニューが出現するかもしれません。

[image: parent user の変更]

Comment: この問題が発生したとき、じぶんはStack Exchangeのサポートに合計三通の問い合わせを送り、コメントをチャットに移したモデレータへ情報提供を求めました。しかし、そのいずれからも一切返信はありませんでした